# Full image responsive on col-md-9 bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I need to design responsive image on col-md-9 and left side col-md-3 menu

Provide suggestions
 attached image for 
 [reference link for image design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ZF9i.jpg)

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row" id="icon_hme">
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 sidebarone" id="resp_design_change"> </div>
        <div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-9 col-md-offset-3 main"> 
            <img id="image_background" class="img-responsive" src="assets/img/background.png"> 
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You'll need to provide what you have attempted. Nobody will want to create this from scratch for you.

Comment: And? SO is not a coding service. Provide is us with code, desired and current result. What have you tried?

Comment: We need to see code. For example, we have no idea if your image should be a background image applied with CSS or an HTML image element.

Comment: Delete the comment and edit your post.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have setup a suitable template for this on [**CodePen**](https://codepen.io/ahdigital/pen/ZvOgNy). Hopefully it can get you started.

**CSS**

```
.img-responsive {
  width: 100%;
}

.no-padding {
  padding: 0;
}

.row-eq-height {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.img-col,
.menu,
header {
  outline: 1px solid #000;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <header>Header</header>
  </div>
  <div class="row row-eq-height" id="icon_hme">
    <div class="menu col-xs-3 sidebarone" id="resp_design_change">Menu</div>
    <div class="img-col col-xs-9 main no-padding">
      <img id="image_background" class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/500x500">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```